# Bug with double letters in hangman

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having problems with double letters. When the user inputs a letter twice, they just keep replacing each other. In the beginning I assign the userArray a list of as's and if the userGuess input is in the hiddenWord I remove one of the a's and replace it with userGuess.I use the .equals() to compare the userArray and hiddenWord. I have tried using the continue; to skip to the next iteration and not delete the first (double occuring word) but when a word has 2 d's, they both have the same index. Like in digger, the 2 g's share the same index. So when I remove

```
void getUserInput(ArrayList<Character> thisArray) {
    System.out.println("The word you are trying to guess for contains: " + letteramnt + " letters");
    correct=false;
    ArrayList<Character> userArray = thisArray;
    Scanner ugScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    correct = false;
    ArrayList<Character>Guesses = new ArrayList<Character>();
    while(correct==false) {
        System.out.println("You have guessed the following:"+ Guesses);
        System.out.println("Enter your guess(character):");
        userGuess = ugScanner.next().charAt(0);
        Guesses.add(userGuess);
        for(char element:hiddenWord) {    
            if(userGuess==element) {   
                System.out.println("Good guess");
                elementindex=hiddenWord.indexOf(element);
                if(userGuess==userArray.get(elementindex)) {
                    System.out.println("continuing");
                    continue;//should skip to next iteration
                }
                userArray.remove(elementindex);//
                userArray.add(elementindex,userGuess);
            }
            if (userArray.equals(hiddenWord)||Guesses.equals(hiddenWord)) {
                correct = true;
                System.out.println("The hidden word was: "+hiddenWord);
                break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elementIndex will be the first index of the letter, you need to scan you hiddenWord string with an index,

```
for(int i=0;i<hiddenWord.length;i++) {    
        element = hiddenWord.charAt(i);
        if(userGuess==element) {   
            System.out.println("Good guess");
            userArray.remove(i);
            userArray.add(i,userGuess);
        }
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I was so bent on using collection based for loops that i didn't see that if I used a regular one I could use i as the index. Someone please close this question. -Thanks once again